# 100% CPU, only with ethernet connection

Tags: ethernet, cpu-usage

I run Windows 7 Ultimate (32), on a Dell Latitude E6500.

After a while the CPU usage suddenly raises to 100% and only reset will help. Taskmanager does not show any program with a high CPU usage (only taskmanager itself).

- I disabled all non-windows services, without effect.
- I disabled Avast Free without effect.

The strange thing is that I have this problem frequently, but only when I am connected to the internet with the ethernet cable at work. At home, with a wireless LAN, I never have this problem.

I use either Firefox of IE, but that does not make any difference. Does anybody have a clue and/or a way to identify the cause of this?

Comment: Did you click show all processes?

Comment: Try booting in safe mode and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: Start -> Run -> `resmon.exe`

Answer (score 4):

Run Resource Monitor. That will show you what's using the CPU.